# QT - deploying a C++ application

Tags: linux, qt

I just started using QT and I have a question regarding some basic stuff.

I have built a project with two files .pro file and .cpp file.

How can I deploy this application and build the .exe file in order to use it in shell?

Can you recommend me any good tutorial for this?

Comment: Are you targeting Windows or Linux? Just you've tagged Linux but .exes are Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compile the file, it will create a binary executable.

It depends on what you have in your project file as to what it will be called, to set the name in the pro file use:

```
TARGET = Stores.bin
```

Or I think it will use the name of the pro file.  Linux executables traditionally don't have extensions like windows.

I then create an installer using bitrock's installer:

http://bitrock.com/

Remembering to package up the libraries as well.

Answer (score 2):

A good source of information on deploying Qt programs is the web page [Deploying Qt Applications](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/deployment.html).

See in particular the "Platform-Specific Notes" at the end.

On the above page, the discussion about static versus shared libraries is also important:

> There are two ways of deploying an application:
>
> - Static Linking
> - Shared Libraries (Frameworks on Mac)
>
> Static linking results in a stand-alone executable. The advantage is that you will only have a few files to deploy. The disadvantages are that the executables are large and with no flexibility (i.e a new version of the application, or of Qt, will require that the deployment process is repeated), and that you cannot deploy plugins.

Answer (score -1):

Use compiler to build your source into executables.
It's better if you use such an IDE, for QT, it's preferrable to use `QTCreator` or `Eclipse`, even `CodeBlock`.

You can refer to some tutorials:

```
http://sector.ynet.sk/qt4-tutorial/
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/tutorials.html
```